# How do I create a 2 row grid of items with just css?

Tags: css

So I have the following html structure:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    ...
</div>
```

The layout I'm trying to achieve is this:

[image]

Now I've figured out that I can achieve this effect on **one** row by using flexbox, with the following:

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

This works for 1 row and gives me the following:

[image]

I was then doing a bit of reading up on css grid, as it sounds like this is one of the reasons it was introduced ie. flexbox works for one dimension where as grid works for two, however I've been unable to wrap my head around it and I'm still not sure it's the correct route.

I'm wondering whether the way I should approach it is to build a grid with 1 column and 2 rows, and then list out the items within these columns.

The alternative would be to have 2 rows and X columns (1 for each item) but I believe this will remove the staggered effect as it'll hold to a grid layout.

Does anyone have any advice on how to achieve this layout?

Comment: You can't have wrapping to two rows without a fixed width to cause the elements to wrap....and CSS-Grid doesn't exactly have wrapping like that.

Comment: You might set the flex-container to a width of 200vw or the like...that might achieve what you are after.

Comment: The problem is I don't know how many items there are going to be - they're coming in from the server

Comment: As I said you don't get wrapping without a defined/definable width...you'll need JS I suspect.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was thinking.. although i was hoping their was a way to due it purely through css

Comment: If items comes from server, then you process them, either with PHP or JS, so you know how much items you have. So you can split them to half

Answer (score 1):

Grid aligns all its rows together, so you lose that staggered effect of flexbox. The easiest solution is to have an outer grid or flexbox that houses two inner flexboxes:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  border: solid 2px gray;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.child {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 4px;
}

.flex:first-child .child:nth-child(even) {
  min-width: 50px;
}

.flex:first-child .child:nth-child(odd) {
  min-width: 75px;
}

.flex:last-child .child:nth-child(even) {
  min-width: 75px;
}

.flex:last-child .child:nth-child(odd) {
  min-width: 65px;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit: If the HTML can't be edited, but you have an outer container and an inner container (i.e. `.wrapper` and `.flex` in this instance) you can also achieve the desired effect by giving the inner container a `min-width` narrower than the `min-width` of the outer container, and setting `flex-wrap: wrap`:

```css
.wrapper {
  border: solid 2px gray;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.flex{
   min-width:900px;
   flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.child {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 4px;
}

.child:nth-child(even) {
  min-width: 50px;
}

.child:nth-child(n+3) {
  min-width: 60px;
}

.child:nth-child(n+5) {
  min-width: 40px;
}

.child:nth-child(odd) {
  min-width: 75px;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This was the only solution I could come up with, but it's going to involve injecting those extra containers into the markup - I was hoping to avoid that

Comment: @alimac83 See my edit. You may be able to achieve the desired effect without adding inner containers to your code, but you will still need two outer containers.